# Automatic npm install --legacy-peer-deps for a single dependency

Tags: npm, dependencies, dependency-management

Assume I have a `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.21.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "credit-card-type": "^8.3.0",
    "csstype": "^3.0.8",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mathjax-full": "^3.2.0",
    "mathjax-react": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that the dependency `mathjax-react` & `mathjax-full` need `react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"`. I have tested with `npm i --force` and `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` and It all seems to work fine with my react version which is `react@17.0.2`.

I wouldn't like to run `npm i --force` and `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` every time i need to install the dependencies, So I was looking for a way to automatically do that only for the `mathjax-react` & `mathjax-full` whenever I run `npm i`. I tried looking in the `.npmrc` [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/npmrc) and this [reference](https://stackabuse.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-configuring-npm/), but could not find a way to do that. What might be a solution for this? Is there a native `npm` solution for this? Or do i have to write a script that reads my `package.json` and runs `npm install` for every dependency alone?

My reasoning is that if i need to install some other dependencies that have conflicts, I'd never be warned about it.

Answer (score 15):

Legacy peer dependencies aren't per-package, they apply to the project as a whole.  It's just that you might need it for your whole project to keep only one or two dependencies happy.  You'll find if you install a package with `--legacy-peer-deps` and then install a different package without that flag, `npm` will complain about the first package again.  So once you need `--legacy-peer-deps`, you need to specify it always no matter what package you install.

[According to the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci), you can set it permanently with:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps=true --location=project
```

This just adds `legacy-peer-deps=true` to the end of the `.npmrc` in your project root.