# Can you add "--legacy-peer-deps" to an individual package in package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I want to to ignore the peer dependencies of only one of the libraries in my package.json (e.g.: `theme-ui`). Is there a way to add such flag to `package.json`?

Comment: No - see [Automatic npm install --legacy-peer-deps for a single dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496618/automatic-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-for-a-single-dependency).

The answers below don't actually limit the `--legacy-peer-deps` to just one package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add `--legacy-peer-deps` in individual packages.

`$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save-dev theme-ui`

**OR**

`$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save theme-ui`

I hope this will help.

Comment: this is only going to work the first time though - subsequent runs of npm install by other users will fail